# Which bugzilla version to install

Tags: linux, unix, rhel5, bugzilla

Which Bugzilla version to download and install http://www.bugzilla.org/download/ on RHEL5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [blog](http://pmtechfusion.blogspot.com/2010/07/bugzilla-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-5x.html):

> Checklist for installing bugzilla on a
>   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.X:
>
> - Download the latest stable version (3.6.3) of bugzilla from the website
>     (http://www.bugzilla.org/)
> - In RHEL5 make sure you install the apache web server that comes with the
>     OS
> - Configure the firewall for apache
> - In RHEL5 make sure you install MySql database that comes with the OS
> - Configure the firewall for MySql

For the rest of the list, read the relevant blog entry.

Comment: what is the error about now..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224630/bugzilla-util-pm-error